# Transfer app data to child Apple ID in same family share

Tags: apple-id, family-sharing

This question has been asked periodically over the years, but I cannot find a definitive answer that works.

On the occasion of buying her a newer iPhone, I am transitioning my daughter to her own AppleID (which is currently in our family share).

She has various games and lifestyle apps with progress and data that was accumulated while using her previous phone (under my AppleID), and wants to transfer them.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

(Newer phone is iOS 12, older one is stuck on iOS 10)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you reviewed [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201085) about using Family Sharing?

Comment: Nothing about app data or transferring between AppleIDs that I could find unfortunately.

Comment: you can not transfer the ownership

Comment: @Buscar웃 I do not want to transfer ownership, the apps can freely be downloaded to her phone as she is part of the Family Sharing, I just want to move the data.

Comment: You can't 'move' the data, that's not possible.  The data is tied to the Apple ID and it can't be transferred.